# .NET DateTimePicker calendar not appearing in PowerShell form

Tags: winforms, powershell, datetimepicker

I am trying to show a DateTimePicker in a WinForms form in PowerShell.  When the form appears, the date can be changed, but hitting the dropdown button doesn't show the calendar.  It seems like something is happening, it's just not visible.

What stupid thing am I missing here?

```
$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(400, 400)
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$form.Text = "When do you want the snapshot to be taken?"
$form.Font = New-Object Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",12)
$form.FormBorderStyle = [Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::Fixed3D

$panel = New-Object Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel
$panel.Height = 400
$panel.Width = 400
$panel.AutoScroll = $true
$panel.FlowDirection = [Windows.Forms.FlowDirection]::TopDown
$panel.WrapContents = $false

$titleText = New-Object Windows.Forms.Label
$titleText.AutoSize = $true
$titleText.Text = "When do you want the snapshot to be taken?"
$panel.Controls.Add($titleText)

$datePicker = New-Object Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker
$datePicker.ShowUpDown = $false
$datePicker.MinDate = $now
$datePicker.MaxDate = $now.AddMonths(3); #arbitrary
$datePicker.MaxSelectionCount = 1
$datePicker.Width = 350
$datePicker.Enabled = $false
$panel.Controls.Add($datePicker)

$form.Controls.Add($panel)
$drc = $form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine on my computer. I copy-pasted your code and added Add-Type to top:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
```

And changed the $datePicker.Enabled:

```
$datePicker.Enabled = $true
```

When run, I can change the date/time and also the dropdown is working as expected:

[image: Powershell Windows Forms datepicker]

Comment: I'm going to mark you as the answer since you got me to look at it more closely.  Ultimately it was my tooling - the PowerShell add-in to VS 2015 Update 1 - that broke this somehow.  Running the script outside of the tooling works fine as you say.  Very odd.